# Recyleview not updating adapter or layout automatically

Tags: android-layout, android-recyclerview, alarmmanager, android-adapter, auto-update

I'm using `alarmmanager` and the code is looking good,not giving any errors but my layout does not update correctly, what is going wrong here? I tried all combinations with alarm manager but my list didn't update automatically.

Here's my main:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements UpdateResultReceiver.Receiver {
private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
Data mData;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
NotificationManager manager;
static int x = 0;
RecyclerAdapter adapter;
private boolean isInited = false;

ArrayList<String> liste;
ArrayList<String> liste2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
    manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    init();
}

private void fillLists() {
    new AsyncCaller().execute();
}

private void init() {
    fillLists();
    scheduleUpdater();
}

private class AsyncCaller extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Data> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Data doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            mData = new Data();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "doInBackground: ", e);
        }
        return mData;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Data data) {
        super.onPostExecute(data);
        if (mData == null) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Hata oluştu", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        liste = data.getList();
        liste2 = data.getList2();
        int s = data.ListSize();

        if (!isInited && liste != null && liste.size() > 0) {
            adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(liste, liste2, MainActivity.this);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));
            isInited = true;
        }
        if (isInited) {
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            int a = adapter.getItemCount();
            if (a != x) {
                generateNotification(MainActivity.this, "Listede Degisim Var");

            }
            x = a;
        }
    }
}

private void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {
    int notificationId = 001;
    Intent viewIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);

    PendingIntent viewPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, viewIntent, 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.dikat).setContentTitle("Bildirim").setContentText(message)
            .setContentIntent(viewPendingIntent).setAutoCancel(true)
            .setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000});

    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);

    notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notificationBuilder.build());
}

@Override
public void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
    fillLists();
}

public void scheduleUpdater() {
    try {
        if (!isAlarmUp(this)) {
            UpdateResultReceiver mReceiver = new UpdateResultReceiver(new Handler());
            mReceiver.setReceiver(this);
                    /* Setting the alarm here */
            Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, PatientListUpdaterReceiver.class);
            alarmIntent.putExtra("receiver", mReceiver);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);

            AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            manager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System
                    .currentTimeMillis(), 10000, pendingIntent);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("asdads", "schedule: " + e.getMessage(), e);
    }

}

public void cancelUpdater(Context context) {
    try {
        if (isAlarmUp(context)) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, PatientListUpdaterReceiver.class);
            PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

            alarmManager.cancel(sender);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("asdasd", "cancel: " + e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}

private boolean isAlarmUp(Context context) {
    return (PendingIntent
            .getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent(context, PatientListUpdaterReceiver.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);
}
}
```

Here's my Adapter:

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends  RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewHolder> {

int sayi=0;
ArrayList<String> liste ,liste2;
static ArrayList<String> liste3 = new ArrayList<>() ;

Context context;
LayoutInflater inflater;
public RecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<String> liste, ArrayList<String> liste2, Context context) {
    this.context=context;
    this.liste=liste;
    this.liste2=liste2;
    inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
}
@Override
public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list, parent, false);



    RecyclerViewHolder viewHolder=new RecyclerViewHolder(v);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {
    liste3.add("a");

    sayi = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < liste3.size(); j++) {
        if (liste3.get(j).equals(liste.get(position))) {
            sayi++;
        }
        if (sayi == 0) {
            holder.imageView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_checkin);
        }
        holder.tv1.setText(liste.get(position));
        holder.tv2.setText(liste2.get(position));
        holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
    }

}


View.OnClickListener clickListener=new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {


        RecyclerViewHolder vholder = (RecyclerViewHolder) v.getTag();
        int position = vholder.getPosition();
        //Toast.makeText(context,"This is position "+position,Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
        vholder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_checkin);
        liste3.add(liste.get(position));
    }
};





@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return liste.size();
}




}
```

Here's the Data part:

```
public class Data {

String ip, db, un, passwords;
Connection connect;
PreparedStatement stmt;
ResultSet rs;


ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> data2 = new ArrayList<>();
public Data(){
    ip = "X.X.X.X";
    un = "sa";
    passwords = "1";
    db = "ANKET";

    connect = CONN(un, passwords, db, ip);
    String query = "SELECT Hasta_dosyano,Notlar FROM Hasta";



    try {
        stmt = connect.prepareStatement(query);
        rs = stmt.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {

                String id = rs.getString("Hasta_dosyano");
                String id2 = rs.getString("Hasta_dosyano");
                String full = id + " " + id2;
                String time = rs.getString("Notlar");
                data.add(full);
                data2.add(time);


        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public ArrayList<String> getList() {
    return data;
}
public ArrayList<String> getList2() {
    return data2;
}
public int ListSize() {
    return data.size();
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private Connection CONN(String _user, String _pass, String _DB,
                        String _server) {
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    Connection conn = null;
    String ConnURL = null;
    try {

        Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
        ConnURL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + _server + ";"
                + "databaseName=" + _DB + ";user=" + _user + ";password="
                + _pass + ";";
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnURL);
    } catch (SQLException se) {
        Log.e("ERRO", se.getMessage());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("ERRO", e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("ERRO", e.getMessage());
    }
    return conn;
}
}
```

Comment: does it get solved ?

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is you change the reference to the data, so the adapter wont understand changes !
Let's show you an example :

```
List data=new ArrayList();
MyAdapter adapter=new MyAdapter(data);
```

Later if you want that the adapter get notified about the changes, you should only use the reference you passed to adapter! You should make `data` a global variable (private,public, whatever you like) so you can have access to it from other places in your code. then you just change data in it and add or remove items and then call notifydatasetchange. That would do the trick.